# what is Delegate Methods of AVPlayerViewController for play music like Mp3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to add action on the all button who shows bellow picture . I add this view through .. following code --

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, _bgView.frame.size.width-20, _bgView.frame.size.height-20);

playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url1];

[_bgView addSubview:playerViewController.view];

_bgView.autoresizesSubviews = TRUE;
```

[image]

So please help me for add the action on this buttons

Comment: Use KVO on `AVPlayer *player` property of `AVPlayerViewController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes..... I resolve that issues... the right code is--

```
_playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_playerViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(10,10, _bgView.frame.size.width-20, _bgView.frame.size.height-20);
_playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url1];
```